# Single sign on (SSO) with open-source IMAP server from desktop application?

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, imap, kerberos, ntlm

I've been reading a lot about this topic but I could not reach a solution.
I wanted to tell what I'm getting and show a little of what I've tried.

In our company, our Windows users are authenticated by Active Directory that is on a Windows Server 2003.
We use an open source mail server installed on Centos 6 for example Postfix with Cyrus Imap.

The goal is to get users to check their mail from any desktop application such as Thunderbird, Outlook, etc ... not have to enter the password again. (sso).

Among the things I've tried was to use Postifix, Cyrsus Imap, Samba, librerias de clientes kerberos, GSSAPI, Thunderbird, Kerberos For Windows and as kdc which uses Windows Server 2003.

Some steps will kick this page: [enter link description here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2751.kerberos-interoperability-step-by-step-guide-for-windows-server-2003.aspx)

Even ask in this forum unable to continue advancing showing even captures whireshark.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754622/server-not-found-in-kerberos-database-while-getting-credentials-for-imap)

Now I'm thinking to try some other alternative.
There are items that you get with NTLM but is accessed from a Web browse not from desktop applications.

I'm thinking that there is no solution to this problem or maybe I did not this seeing.

Has anyone been able to achieve something?, That way I recommend following?.

Thanks for any help!.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is perfectly possible; I have all those pieces working myself, or very similar. Because of my setup I have only made Thunderbird work with KfW installed and using its GSSAPI DLL, but it has the option to use SSPI (the Windows native Kerberos provider), so it ought to work that way as well.

The first thing I would do is get Kerberos working with Cyrus and Postfix. You'll need to get them Kerberos service principals: imap/hostname@DOMAIN and smtp/hostname@DOMAIN. You can use setspn.exe to add these to some AD account (any one will do); omit the @DOMAIN part in that command. Then you'll need files containing the principal keys to give to Cyrus and Postfix, called keytabs. You can use ktpass.exe, but that's an awful program -- you can also just use *ktutil* on Unix (assuming MIT Kerberos) to make a matching keytab using the AD account's password.

On the server side, for Cyrus you'll need the GSSAPI SASL library installed. You can use the imtest program (part of cyrus-clients on Debian) to test and get GSSAPI/Kerberos IMAP authentication working; use "kinit username@DOMAIN" on Unix to get Kerberos credentials from a domain controller to use. I've only set up sendmail for Kerberos, not Postfix, myself.